# Until a process has started, do something

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

So I have a background program that starts with Windows, minimized to system tray icon. Once it loads I need it to constantly start checking if a process has started (for example VLC). Once the process has started, It must wait for it to close in order to start doing stuff and then get back to check if it has started. I've been trying to do this for a while now, but I just can't figure out how.

How would I constantly check if a program has started?

Comment: If your app has admin privileges, you can use the [ManagementEventWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementeventwatcher) class, setting the [WqlEventQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.wqleventquery) to `Win32_ProcessTrace`. You can specify a Process name or no name, to receive start/terminate events relate to one or all processes. If you need an example, let me know.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out.

Comment: All right. Note that when you use these queries, the name of the Process requires the full name: it includes the extension (while the Process class doesn't require it). So, if you want to receive a notification when, e.g., notepad is started/terminated, you have to specify "notepad.exe" as the name of the watched Process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to have the Background Deamon look for aprogramm of a specific name. Unfortunately this not overly reliable (due to name overlaps), would require a lot of polling and runs the risk of race conditions (the process starting when your deamon is still working).

What *would* be reliable, is if it is the *Deamon* that actually starts the foreground process. That way it could do work before `Process.Start()` and after `Process.WaitForExit()`, with full information when both states happen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netcore-3.1

Steam is a good example. It is a single-instance process, so any further requests can be relayed to the running instance. The desktop links to programms/games are actually weblinks - not programm links. Those links use the :steam protocoll, wich is associated with the steam processes. So it goes like this:

- user klicks on a WebLink with :steam procotoll
- Windows resolves to hand this into a commandline call to the steam programm
- A instance is started with the proper order in via commandline. Single instancing will not allow a 2nd instanc to start, but hand the request over a already running one
- the already or now suddenly running instance calls the programm, having full data on when it starts and ends - being the actuall logical caller